# unable to get radio button value in angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, angular-ngmodel

We are tired to get radio button value.We tried like this

.html

```
 <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="ApplySelectelements(result)">Apply</button>
 </ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-item ng-repeat="Cate in Categorys | filter:searchQuery">
        <ion-radio ng-model="result"   ng-value="'{{Cate}}'">{{Cate}}</ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
```

JS

```
$scope.ApplySelectelements = function (result){
            alert('Select Categry is Apply ' +result);
         }
```

In alert we got `Result is Undefined`
Please guide to us.What wrong in my code

Comment: What is result in `ng-click="ApplySelectelements(result)"` ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi thanks for reply. result is ng-model="result". Please check once .please tell me what wrong  in our code

Comment: can you provide fiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
       <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="ApplySelectelements(result)">Apply</button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-item >
        <ion-radio name="myRadios" ng-repeat="Cate in Categorys" ng-model="result" ng-value="Cate">{{Cate}}</ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: Please change this with your code

<ion-item ng-repeat="Cate in Categorys | filter:searchQuery">
        <ion-radio ng-model="result"   ng-value="{{Cate}}">{{Cate}}</ion-radio>
    </ion-item>  or please check this link http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/forms/radiobuttoninput/

Comment: @Jihin Raju Thanks for reply.We tried as you said but no luck .Please guide to us

Comment: @JihinRaju yes we tried you code .but unable to get

Comment: @PavanAlapati do one thing change ng-value to value

Comment: @PavanAlapati add the ng-repeat in icon-radio directive

Comment: @JihinRaju really thanks for support to us.but Still we don't' have luck .we tried above code

Comment: @PavanAlapati remove the filter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109632/discussion-between-jihin-raju-and-pavan-alapati).